# DELETE IGNORE on Tables with Foreign Keys Can Break Replication

Tags: mysql, replication

> I am using replication in a MYSQL database. I have read some where DELETE IGNORE command on Tables with Foreign Keys can break Replication. Is it true? If it is true then how can workaround this?

Comment: Actually, I have put this question as there is nothing found about this topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read it here: https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/02/02/stop-delete-ignore-on-tables-with-foreign-keys-can-break-replication/

The details of how DELETE IGNORE can be unsafe for replication is shown in that blog.

The solution to work around the issues to do either one of:

- Don't use DELETE IGNORE
- Use Row-Based Replication by setting binlog-format=ROW

Comment: Since the default is moving toward RBR, this problem will become rare.